# Why does +(5,6) return 6 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm designing a domain specific language and was wondering if I should allow it to use the operator "+" as a function (5+6 would be equivalent to +(5,6))

Trying to call "+" as a function in javascript returns the following results

```
+(5,6) // returns 6
+("foo",7) // returns 7
+(3,2,9) // returns 9
+("foo", "bar") // returns NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

So actually this snippet

```
+(5,6)
```

is equivalent to

```
+6 // evaluates to 6
```

Comment: Actually, you have a typo in your last line. It's equivalent to the second operand, so `+6`.

Comment: holy crap: I thought I know all about JS but I'd never heard of the comma operator!

Comment: This goes all the way back to C.

Comment: @ErikAllik -- Forget you ever learned about it. *grin* It lets you write some amazingly tight code and do some ungodly things inside of conditionals -- but MAN it leads to hard-to-read code.

Comment: sorry but what is *grin*?